# Limit of an indeterminated form?

Tags: asymptotics, indeterminate-forms

I want to find:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}X_{t}$$

where:

$$X_{t} = \frac{A_{t}^{a}}{B_{t}}$$

I know that:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}A_{t}=0$$

and

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}B_{t}=0$$

Can I say with certainty that:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}X_{t}=\frac{0^{a}}{0} = \left\{\begin{array}{l l}
 0 & \text{if $a > 1$}\\
 1 & \text{if $a=1$}\\
\infty & \text{if $a<1$}
\end{array} \right.$$

This is, can I compare dominance of expressions?

Note that I don't have closed-form expressions for $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ so I cannot do L'Hopital here. I do know their limit though, as given above.

Comment: More information about $A_t$ and $B_t$ is needed, also if we take $A_t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$, $B_t=\frac{1}{t^2}$ then two of the expressions you give are not true, when $a=2>1$ and $a=1$.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$? Sequences? Real functions?